# Portable application with a database

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, ms-access, portability

I am looking at creating a simple application for my wife for tracking her product details etc. 
I would like to create an application that she can use on a USB stick. The reason for this is that I want to be able to use it on the USB so we can use it on her laptop, my laptop/desktop and any other machine that she wants to. 
Can I create a .exe from a win forms application or an Access application that has a database attached that will work in all my scenarios and what type of database could I use without modifying the computers environment? 
I have used a little of Access and Microsoft SQL Server before but is there a way to make these portable on a USB without having to install anything on the computers? 
I have not used or looked at SQL Lite before but I have seen a few examples of these in other forums and wondering if I need to use this or can I use a technology I already know.
The database will be no more than 6 tables and will be very small less than 50MB to start with.
Any ideas or suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: you could always go with XML, free , and works anywhere, and 50MB is quite alot for just your wife's contacts, i;d be surpised if it got to half that

Comment: @ScottSelby Yeah I know 50MB is a lot for contacts. I am future proofing myself/answer as she will one day be adding to it with her products/suppliers/costs etc. Do you by anychance have any examples with XML as a db?

Comment: Pretty much any example of XML is an an example of XML as a database. For example: `<customers><customer><name>John Doe</name><phonenumber>888-777-7777</phonenumber></customer><customer><name>Jane Doe</name><phonenumber>555-555-5555</phonenumber></customer></customers>`

SQLLite is another alternative (although I haven't actually used it myself so I can't say too much more about it).

Comment: @msm8bball thanks for your example. That looks easy enough to try and grasp the concept. I will look into that more.

Comment: So you want it to run on a Apple?  A USB does not have an OS.

Comment: If possible running on Apple and PC would be fantastic. The main use would be for PC but we do have an Apple laptop which we have use of from time to time.

Comment: Since you want it to run on Windows and OS X, you should write in something cross platform compatible such as Java, rather than the .NET framework platform. Or write two apps, both with access to the database file. But that's double the work. Or you could write it as a web application (such as ASP.NET). Does the app have to be custom? There are plenty of existing off the shelf products that could do what you're wanting.

Comment: @msm8bball Thanks for the ideas. I think I will stick to .net with XML since I have hardly used Java and see how much she uses the system before I put too much time into it.

Answer (score 1):

Firebird embedded is a good option. And when you need a Firebord db server standalone to be shared by multiple clients, you don't need to change your app codes.

for tracking her client details etc, please have a look at http://www.fonlow.com/opencontacts/, and this program could be portable.

Answer (score 0):

While this is not a very "StackOverflow" type answer, but why not just use this http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/thunderbird_portable it is a email client but has a address book in it.

Unless your wifes file structure is super custom, this might be a better solution ... in my perspective, XML is the option if you want custom, but if you want to make a .NET app, I would suggest .NET 2.0 as it is pretty much everywhere, not all systems are up to date on their .NET install

Comment: Thanks @AAP for your answer. Unfortunately I would like to expand on the Contacts later on so I will need other tables and information that I could get from using your link.